# What is the use of replacing paranthesis with curly brackets when passing parameters to a function?

Tags: lua

```lua
local function bruh(a,b)
return a.hai, a.yey
end
print(bruh(
{hai = "hoho"},
{yey = 11}
)) --> hoho nil
```

I tried to change the code a little bit:

```lua
local function bruh(a,b)
return a.hai, a.yey
end
print(bruh{
{hai = "hoho"},
{yey = 11}
})--> nil nil
```

What's the problem with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bruh** is a function and in simple cases you should use parenthesis `()` to place your function's parameters (`{hai = "hoho"}` is a parameter). In the second block of code, you used curly braces `{}` instead, which works a little differently. It's like calling a singular table as a parameter. Consider this:

```
function test(word)
  print("The word is...")
  print(word)
end
```

You might try and call this function a few different ways and the output will change based on how you call it.
`test("Chicken")` output:

```
The word is...
Chicken
```

You called the string *"chicken"* through the normal method and it was used by the function. But what if you call it with the curly braces?

`test{"Chicken"}` output:

```
The word is...
table: 0x204a710 --the actual location in computer memory of the table {"Chicken"} you wrote
```

This is equivalent to calling `test({"Chicken"})`. Run it and the output will be the same, but with a different location printed, but the location of the table isn't important to you. What you could do to access "Chicken" this way is to index the parameter table like any other table.

```
function test(word)
  print("The word is...")
  print(word[1])
end

test{"Chicken"}
```

Output:

```
The word is...
Chicken
```

The output would be the same if you called `test({"Chicken"})`

So when you call "bruh **{**{hai = "hoho"}, {yey = 11}**}** ", the parameter *"a"* of **bruh** is actually the table made by the outer pair of curly braces (in bold), so *a.hai* does not exist and will return a *nil* value. The curly braces should really only be used when you will pass one table as a parameter and extract the rest of the values inside the function, because you technically can't pass anything after the table. For example, if you wanted the function to print *a.hai* and *a.yey* you could write this:
`print(bruh{hai = "hello", yey = "Bye"})`
But ask yourself: How would you include a *"b"* table? You included a second parameter in your Bruh function so I'm assuming you intend to write one soon. Just use the parenthesis in this case, it will save you headaches.

Comment: I tried to solve this problem before asking. About *b* table, I wrote an argument before but then I forgot to add it back(actually I'm too lazy)

Comment: Nvm, I found the reason why